# How to receive extra $_POST data in PHP server using Android Multipart

Tags: php, android, post, multipart

I have been struggling for about a week trying different ways to upload my audio file along with user data so I can determine what to save in the database.
File is uploaded successfully but I can't get the user name.
@user5155835 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935317/android-php-send-string-alongwith-multipart-data) had the same problem and apparently was solved by him but I can't get it to work.
Please I need some help with this. I have trashed this code and used different other approaches but I can't never see the POST variable.
 In my struggle I'm back to this code again, not to mention that I'm dealing with multiple asyncTask processes and compiling the libraries in gradle was a nightmare.

In Android

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName));
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Allow Outputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                // Don't use a cached copy.
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                // Use a post method.
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }
                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user\"" +params[0] +"\""+lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


                // close streams
                Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
```

In the server.

```
$email = $_POST['user'];
echo "email is ".$email;

    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE email = '".$email."' ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
    if($objResult)
    {
       //upload file
    }
```

From server

```
E/Debug: File is written
E/Debug: Server Response email is
```

Comment: Very strange that you have problems. Code for posting a file and some parameters has been posted so often on stackoverflow. So why is it that you cant find it? In principle every parameter and its value has to be send between two boundary lines. Like the file. So google.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small suggestion for you. If you didn't have much data that need to be posted to the server what you can do is. Pass data as get parameters and file as post parameters. So you can get user and other data from $_Get["user"]

for example if your url is: http://example.com/TestPost.php

then you should make it like http://example.com/TextPost.php?user=test@gmail.com.

This is not good solutions but for now it will work for you.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [Stack Overflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/about), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [Stack Overflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/about), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).